# how to get data from localStorage next js 13

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I'm new to handling Next JS, I'm having trouble creating middleware in Next, I want to get data from local storage and it always fails.

middleware.ts

```
import { key, timeEncryptKey, tokenEncryptKey, userEncryptKey } from '@/lib/cryptoJs/encrypt'
import { getLocalStorage } from '@/lib/localStorage/page'
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server'
import type { NextRequest } from 'next/server'


export async function middleware(req: NextRequest) {
  try {
    const dataToken = getLocalStorage(tokenEncryptKey);
    const dataSession = getLocalStorage(timeEncryptKey);
    const sessionData = !dataSession ? null : parseInt(CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(dataSession, key).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8), 10);
    console.log(sessionData);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error handling token:', error);
  }
}
```

localStorage.ts

```
export const setLocalStorage = (key: string, value: any) => {
  if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
    localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(value));
  }
};

export const getLocalStorage = (key: string): any => {
  if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
    const data = localStorage.getItem(key);
    return data ? JSON.parse(data) : null;
  }
  return null;
};

export const removeLocalStorage = (key: string) => {
  if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
    localStorage.removeItem(key);
  }
};
```

I don't use next auth , but I have also tried using next auth for middleware , but it doesn't work either

Comment: What issue does it give, Does it throws any error, if yes what? Also is this code executing in the browser or on the server? Because localStorage is not available on the server.

Answer (score 0):

next.js middlewares run on the server. `window` is defined only on the browser. there is no way you access `window` api from the server. in your `getLocalStorage` function, `typeof window` is always `undefined` so your function will always return `null` value.